# Web api HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-web-api

Hello I have an error 500 (internal server error) when I run the code below. My issue is that **I have no trace at all of the error**. It seems that visual studio is unable to catch it.

The following code returns a Candidate if I try to add **pers** to **candidate** the code fail and i get error 500. The thing is PersonAddressDescription implement AddressDescription is inheritance the problem ?

```
public class CheckController : ApiController
{
    public Candidate Get()
    {
        PersonAddressDescription pers = new PersonAddressDescription();

        Candidate candidate = new Candidate();

        //IF I REMOVE THIS NO PROBLEM
        candidate.address = pers;

        return candidate;
    }
}
```

AddressDescription class

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(CompanyAddressDescription))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(PersonAddressDescription))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17626")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.crif-online.ch/webservices/crifsoapservice/v1.00")]
    public abstract partial class AddressDescription : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private Location locationField;

        private ContactItem[] contactItemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public Location location {
            get {
                return this.locationField;
            }
            set {
                this.locationField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("location");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("contactItems", Order=1)]
        public ContactItem[] contactItems {
            get {
                return this.contactItemsField;
            }
            set {
                this.contactItemsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("contactItems");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

PersonAddressDescription class that implement AddressDescription

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.17626")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.crif-online.ch/webservices/crifsoapservice/v1.00")]
    public partial class PersonAddressDescription : AddressDescription {

        private string firstNameField;

        private string lastNameField;

        private string maidenNameField;

        private Sex sexField;

        private bool sexFieldSpecified;

        private string birthDateField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
        public string firstName {
            get {
                return this.firstNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.firstNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("firstName");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string lastName {
            get {
                return this.lastNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.lastNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("lastName");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=2)]
        public string maidenName {
            get {
                return this.maidenNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.maidenNameField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("maidenName");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=3)]
        public Sex sex {
            get {
                return this.sexField;
            }
            set {
                this.sexField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("sex");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
        public bool sexSpecified {
            get {
                return this.sexFieldSpecified;
            }
            set {
                this.sexFieldSpecified = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("sexSpecified");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=4)]
        public string birthDate {
            get {
                return this.birthDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.birthDateField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("birthDate");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>I suspect that the object you retrieved (`addResp`) contains circular references somewhere in its object graph. Circular references cannot be JSON serialized.</strike>

For example try putting the following code inside your controller to test what happens when you attempt to JSON serialize this instance:

```
TypeIdentifyAddressResponse addResp = ws.identifyAddress("test");
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addResp);
```

---

UPDATE:

It seems that `AddressDescription` is an abstract class and your actual instance is `PersonAddressDescription`. You need to indicate that to the serializer by using the [`[KnownType]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[KnownType(typeof(PersonAddressDescription))]
[KnownType(typeof(CompanyAddressDescription))]
...
public abstract partial class AddressDescription : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
{
    ...
}
```

As an alternative if you don't want to further pollute your (already polluted) domain models with other attributes you could also define the known type inside your `WebApiConfig.cs`:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SetSerializer<Candidate>(
    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Candidate),
    new Type[] { typeof(PersonAddressDescription) }));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Is there a workaround ? Do you think I can manually transform the reference class to remove these circular references ?

Comment: Yes, you could use a view model. Define a new class which doesn't contain circular references and only include the properties you really need. Then map between your domain object (`addResp`) to this new type you defined and return the view model.

Comment: Well I just tried the JsonConvert and it works it returns me a string with all the informations ...

Comment: Hmm, then there must be something else. What format are you using? Is it JSON or XML? Also could you please post the full exception stacktrace you are getting? How are you calling this Web API method?

Comment: That's exactly the problem I don't get any exception ... I call the api thru a web browser. The format for the serialization used is xml.

Comment: I realize that if I modify addResp and set the property addressMatchResult to null it works. I've posted both references.

Comment: How does the `AddressMatchResult` type look like?

Comment: What do you see exactly in the browser when you call the method?

Comment: When I call the empty Get i see the xml representation of addResp in the browser. If call it with a parameter I get error 500 with no information and no error in visual studion get caught.

Comment: You only get 500 in your browser? Usually you should see the response from the server in your browser. What is it? Do you get an YSOD or something?

Comment: Yes it is unusual I know but I only get error 500 in the browser no stack trace. I've digged a little bit and I seem to have discovered what cause the trouble. If I remove the candidates property from my response (addResp.addressMatchResult.candidates = null) it's working the xml is returned to the browser. Is it possible that the bug is related to lists ?

Comment: Could you show the `Candidate` class? I am not aware of such bugs. You could subscribe to the `Application_Error` event in your `Global.asax` which will be invoked and you will be able to intercept the exception to get more details. Right now I cannot guess. It would be better for you to debug your code.

Comment: Woow, that's a hell of a mess. Do you really need all this information to be serialized? I would very strongly recommend you defining a view model.

Comment: Yeah it's true and you are right I'm gonna make a ViewModel. But still I want to find what's causing the trouble I've edited my post. As you can see the problem lays in PersonAddressDescription. If I remove it from my candidate object I can display it well. That class implements AddressDescription is that a possible source of problem ? Can inheritance be the problem ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. You need to decorate the `AddressDescription` class with the `[KnownType]` attribute in order to indicate to the Web API XML serializer the possible known types of this abstract type. I have updated my answer to illustrate with an example.

Comment: Yeah !!!!! Thanks a lot !!! The question was badly formulated in part because the trace do not work with this which I still don't understand but it's working. Thanks